# How to copy contents from one CSV into another CSV with powershell?

Tags: powershell, csv, merge

i have 2 csv files:
each got 3 columns ,
i want to compare the first column and if it matches it will copy the content in the other columns
for example:

1 csv:

```
column1   column2    column3
aaa       bla        baba
ccc       bla        babab3
abc       bla        bababa3
```

2 csv:

```
column1   column4     column5
abc       dla2        blabla2
ddd       dla         blabla
ccc       dla1        blabla1
aaa       dla1        blabla1
```

updated csv:

```
column1   column2   column3   column4   column5 
aaa       bla        baba     dla1      blabla1
ccc       bla        babab3   dla1      blabla1
abc       bla        bababa3  dla2      blabla2
```

thanks,

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Is `column1` always a unique identifier?

Comment: yes, and it will be the only 1 who can have a match in both csv's

Comment: Apologies for being a bit blunt, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Generally here, it's expected that SO is the last stop on your journey to a solution, not the first place you go. You should first research and attempt this already yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
# Import both CSV files.
$rowsA = Import-Csv 1.csv
$rowsB = Import-Csv 2.csv

# The name of the shared column to join by.
$sharedCol = 'Column1'

# Get the column names of 2.csv, excluding the shared one.
$colsB = $rowsB[0].psobject.Properties.Name -ne $sharedCol

# Create a map (hashtable) that maps the shared column
# values to the column values of the matching 2.csv rows.
$map = @{}
$rowsB.ForEach({ $map[$_.$sharedCol] = $_.psobject.Properties[$colsB] })

# Construct empty helper properties for those $sharedCol values in 1.csv
# that have no counterpart in 2.csv
$emptyPropsB = 
  ([pscustomobject] @{} | Select-Object -Property $colsB).psobject.Properties

$rowsA | ForEach-Object {
  $rowA = $_
  # Find the matching 2.csv row's column values. If not found, use empty ones.
  $colValuesB = $map[$rowA.$sharedCol]
  if (-not $colValuesB) { $colValuesB = $emptyPropsB }
  # Append the column values from the 2.csv row to the 1.csv row at hand.
  $colValuesB.ForEach({ $rowA.psobject.Properties.Add($_) })
  $rowA # Output the merged row.
} # | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 updated.csv
```

<sup>Outputs to the *display*; remove the `#` from the last line to export to a CSV file instead.</sup>

Note: If you want to *skip* 1.csv rows that have no matching 2.csv row, replace 
`if (-not $colValuesB) { $colValuesB = $emptyPropsB }` with 
`if (-not $colValuesB) { return }`
Also, you then don't need the `$emptyPropsB = ...` statement.